# rails server won't start - broke down the setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Yesterday the app was running fine on development. Today, It asked about a missing gem. I ended up upgrading the gems via sudo bundle install. At the end, it didn't work either so I went back to gem 1.4.2. I'm using ruby 2.0.0p247, rails 4.0 and ubuntu.

When I type rails s I get:

```
    boot.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

I just can't figure out what went wrong. Bundle install says everything is ready.

Comment: Do you have the same error if you run instead 'bundle exec rails s'?

Comment: No! if I run bundle exec it works... could you explain why?

Comment: bundle exec rails s runs the server in the context of your Gemfile (last bundle install). rails s does almost exactly the same thing, except if you installed several versions of gems locally and your Gemfile doesn't say which version you want to use.

Comment: You should write an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always run:

```
bundle exec rails s
```

This will ensure you're using the right gems versions as bundled in your Gemfile.